# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tiles.TilesException: method <init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V not found

Tags: struts2, struts, tiles

Getting above error when starting my struts application.
 The following is the export order.

```
    /WEB-INF/src
    /WEB-INF/lib/freemarker-2.3.16.jar
    /WEB-INF/lib/javassist-3.7.ga.jar
    /WEB-INF/lib/ognl-3.0.jar
    JRE System library[jrocket... ]
    /WEB-INF/lib/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
    /WEB-INF/lib/commons-digester-1.8.1.jar
    /WEB-INF/lib/commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
    /WEB-INF/lib/commons-io-1.3.2.jar
    /WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
    /WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
    /WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.14.jar
    /WEB-INF/lib/struts2-config-browser-plugin-2.2.1.jar
    /WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.2.1.jar
    /WEB-INF/lib/struts2-tiles-plugin-2.2.1.jar
    /WEB-INF/lib/tiles-api-2.1.2.jar
    /WEB-INF/lib/tiles-compat-2.1.2.jar
    /WEB-INF/lib/tiles-jsp-2.1.2.jar
    /WEB-INF/lib/tiles-servlet-2.1.2.jar
    /WEB-INF/lib/xwork-core-2.2.1.jar
    weblogic/api.jar
    json-2010.01.05.jar
    /WEB-INF/lib/tiles-core-2.1.2.jar
```

Please help. I will be very happy

2014-06-30 13:51:39,448 INFO  org.apache.tiles.context.AbstractTilesApplicationContextFactory.createFactory:72 - Initializing Tiles2 application context. . .
    2014-06-30 13:51:39,458 INFO  org.apache.tiles.context.AbstractTilesApplicationContextFactory.createFactory:91 - Finished initializing Tiles2 application context.
    2014-06-30 13:51:39,480 INFO  org.apache.tiles.factory.TilesContainerFactory.initializeContainer:362 - Initializing Tiles2 container. . .
        (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V not found.
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tiles.TilesException: method (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V not found
        at org.apache.tiles.factory.NotAvailableFeatureException.(NotAvailableFeatureException.java:71)
        at org.apache.tiles.portlet.context.NotAPortletEnvironmentException.(NotAPortletEnvironmentException.java:71)
        at org.apache.tiles.portlet.context.PortletTilesRequestContextFactory.(PortletTilesRequestContextFactory.java:68)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

> ```
> 2014-06-30 13:51:39,524 INFO  org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletUtil.setContainer:151 - Removing TilesContext for context: weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext
> <Jun 30, 2014 1:51:39 PM EDT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID '1404150699134' for task '0'. Error is: 'weblogic.application.ModuleException: '
> weblogic.application.ModuleException: 
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1510)
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:482)
>     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
>     at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
>     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
>     Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tiles.TilesException: method <init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V not found
>     at org.apache.tiles.factory.NotAvailableFeatureException.<init>(NotAvailableFeatureException.java:71)
>     at org.apache.tiles.portlet.context.NotAPortletEnvironmentException.<init>(NotAPortletEnvironmentException.java:71)
>     at org.apache.tiles.portlet.context.PortletTilesRequestContextFactory.<init>(PortletTilesRequestContextFactory.java:68)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
> <Jun 30, 2014 1:51:39 PM EDT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149202> <Encountered an exception while attempting to commit the 7 task for the application 'inhouse_brands'.> 
> <Jun 30, 2014 1:51:39 PM EDT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating start task for application 'inhouse_brands'.> 
> <Jun 30, 2014 1:51:39 PM EDT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
> weblogic.application.ModuleException: 
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1510)
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:482)
>     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
>     at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
>     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
>     Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tiles.TilesException: method <init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V not found
>     at org.apache.tiles.factory.NotAvailableFeatureException.<init>(NotAvailableFeatureException.java:71)
>     at org.apache.tiles.portlet.context.NotAPortletEnvironmentException.<init>(NotAPortletEnvironmentException.java:71)
>     at org.apache.tiles.portlet.context.PortletTilesRequestContextFactory.<init>(PortletTilesRequestContextFactory.java:68)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Add this jars in your `WEB-INF/lib` folder

> commons-lang3-3.1.jar
>   commons-lang-2.4.jar
>   slf4j-api-x.x.x.jar
>   slf4j-log4j12-x.x.x.jar
>   log4j-x.x.x.jar

**Most importantly this jar is not in your project, So first download it and add it to your build path.**

> tiles-core.2.x.x.jar
>   tiles-template-2.x.x.jar
>   tiles-portlet-2.x.x.jar

You can choose version by yourself as per your project need.e.g. `commons-lang-x.x,jar`. Also reply if you get error.

And if you are new user to stack overflow then I will suggest you to learn how to accept answer [Please see click HERE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

**EDIT :**
Also I would like to tell you that `struts2-tiles-plugin-2.2.1.jar` depends on **tiles 2.0.6** not tiles 2.2.1. Well, it does not matter. But it was just for your information. You should use proper version of tiles which should be compatible with your struts. At least try once using compatible versions.

What your error says is a resource could not be used because it is not in a portlet environment.

I will suggest you to [Learn portlet integration of tiles](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/4.2/official/liferay-portlet-development-guide-4.2/multipage/ch03s02.html)

You are missing `tiles-portlet-2.x.x.jar` or  `portlet-ext.xml` file

**Edit 2:**

Check `rt.jar` in your JRE.

If you don't have it on your classpath you will not have access to any of those classes you need to use like `java.lang.String` or `java.io.File`.

Comment: I added those 2 to my build path and still same error??

Comment: add full stacktrace. full eror log is required. copy paste full stacktrace from your console to your question. Click on edit question link and copy paste full stack trace there. So I can understand.

Comment: I have updated the answer for you. And I am waiting for your stack trace.

Comment: I can't paste it in, it's giving me this annoying error that i need to add 4 spaces to every line!!! and the Ctrl K doesnt work.

Comment: Did you add tiles-core-2.x.x.jar or use `tile 2.0.6`? And without error information we can not help you

Comment: Is  tiles-core-2.x.x.jar same as /WEB-INF/lib/tiles-core-2.1.2.jar?

Comment: As you can see I added have it in the last line of my comment.

Comment: Please answer quickly, Jeremy is on my case.

Comment: Do you have `tiles-portlet-2.x.x.jar` in your build path? You are not using portlet enviornment. That is what your error indicates. What are your `view-resolver` and `tilesconfigure` values in your xml?

Comment: In `tiles.xml` Are you using portlet definition?

Comment: I don't those 2 tags in any of my xml files.

Comment: I have tiles-portlet-2.2.2 in my build path. But don't have any portlet definitions. I have <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> <!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
      "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">

<tiles-definitions> etc..

Comment: The funny thing is that my friend has the exact same application on his computer and i mimicked all the jar files and export order and still i have the problem and he doesn't. the only difference is that i have the jrocket jre and he has another one. should that make a difference?

Comment: yes. JRE contains `java.lang` package. in that `String` class is implemented. Check your JRE for `java.lang.string`

Comment: If you do not have download `rt.jar` as I instructed in my answer edit portion. It should run.